# $geoWithin $center with pymongo aggregation throws error

Tags: mongodb, pymongo

This is my aggregation:

```
query = [
    {'$match' : { 'location' : { 
        '$geoWithin': {'$center' : [ [lng,lat], distance ] }} }}
]
dumps(DB.venue.aggregate(query))
```

However it throws:

```
OperationFailure: command SON([('aggregate', u'venue'), ('pipeline', 
[{'$match': {'location': {'$geoWithin': {'$center': [[u'23.729310', u'37.983716'], 
0.0023544184586407157]}}}}])]) failed: exception: Malformed geo query: { $geoWithin: 
{ $center: [ [ "23.729310", "37.983716" ], 0.002354418458640716 ] } }
```

I have also tried with `$within` instead of `$geoWithin` and `$centerSphere` instead of `$center` but no. Typically the find() query works with within and center ([docs](http://api.mongodb.org/python/current/examples/geo.html?highlight=within#querying)).

Is it a bug or just not supported by pymongo? Because the java driver work fine with `$geoWithin` and `$centerSphere`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First things first, the correct query is:

```
{'$match' : {'location' : {'$geoWithin': {'$centerSphere': [[lng,lat], distance] }} }},
```

however the lng and lat above that I was passing were not floats but unicode chars so that threw the error.